Installing edbee library on Linux
I'm trying to install the edbee-lib. So far, I have

Pulled the repo
Built it with

mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DBUILD_WITH_QT5=False -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/mitjancic/Qt/6.5.3/gcc_64/ ..
make


Tried installing it with sudo make install.

The ouput of the last command is
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/QsLog/QsLog.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/QsLog/QsLogDest.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/QsLog/QsLogDestConsole.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/QsLog/QsLogDestFile.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/QsLog/QsLogDestFunctor.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/QsLog/QsLogDisableForThisFile.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/QsLog/QsLogLevel.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/QsLog/QsLogMessage.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/QsLog/QsLogSharedLibrary.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libQsLog.so
-- Set non-toolchain portion of runtime path of "/usr/local/lib/libQsLog.so" to ""

So it appears only QsLog was installed but not the edbee library. Even if I check the /usr/local/lib/ or /usr/local/include/, I only see QsLog there.
Would anybody know what I am doing wrong?
Ultimately, I want to use edbee in a different cmake-c++ based project.

https://github.com/edbee/edbee-lib/blob/master/edbee-lib/CMakeLists.txt I don't see any install targets defined for this project. I guess you can contribute to this lib and implement the correct CMake packaging. Or create an issue and ask the authors to take a look.

And QSLog files are installed, because ../vendor/qslog/ is not EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL, and it has some installation rules.
